# How to use oauth2 to dowload_data in bulkloader

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, bulkloader

I'm using builkloader in Python, my command like below:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=all.csv --kind=all 
  --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/remote_api --namespace=mynamespace
```

it worked, and I can download it normally after input my email and password.
I do not want to input email and password manually, and try  --oauth2 option. But it's still prompt me to input email and password in console.

I tried to Google it but have no reason.

Thank in advanced !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
appcfg.py --oauth2_refresh_token=token update myapp/
```

[Link to docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth)

Comment: Thanks !  the --oauth2_refresh_token  option help we use the same token for all the time. I wonder how to use --oauth2 option which load token from file

Comment: From the help link above - A page will appear in your web browser prompting you for authentication. (If you used the --noauth_local_webserver option, then appcfg.py will instead show you a URL to copy/paste into your browser.) Log in if necessary. The page will ask whether you wish to give appcfg access. Click OK. (If you used the --noauth_local_webserver option, then you will be given a token that you will need to supply to the prompt from appcfg.py.)

Comment: And further your question - From now on, when you run appcfg.py --oauth2, it uses the saved authentication token.

Comment: yeah ! I know that, I have authentication token file after first authentication. But it doesn't use the saved authen file to get authen. I also copied the refresh_token from that file too

Comment: weird I used it and it found the token without me doing anything extra?